# Getting Shared Preferences from GCMBroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, notifications, sharedpreferences, google-cloud-messaging

I have in my application a value that is saves in the Shared Preferences in the `MainActivity` which I need to use in my `GCMBroadcastReceiver` whenever a notification arrives for my app.

Can I access the Shared Preferences from the `GCMBroadcastReceiver`? Or maybe there is another way to receive this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had to use the context passed to the onReceive method

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getsharedPreferences("prefs name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

use following code for saving values and retrieving values.

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
   PreferenceManager manager;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {

      manager = (PreferenceManager) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
      SharedPreferences preferences = manager.getSharedPreferences();
    // handle here your broadcast receiver specific code. 
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not work because the `GcmBroadcastReceiver` is not an activity.

Comment: But you will be having access to context in the BroadcastReciever, by that can get application context. Mainly you need do only one thing save the Preferences in ApplicationContext not any component specific context. Then only your preferences will be available through out application.